# Guava Joiner on SortedSet

Tags: java, sorting, guava

I want to get a string of comma separated values, sorted.
if using a TreeSet for that purpose, and then using

```
Joiner.on(',').join(someSortedSet);
```

will I get the string values sorted ?

Comment: I'd say trying would have been faster than asking the question, though.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd even if trying does return it sorted, it assures nothing.

Comment: True, admittedly. But reading the sources or debugging would have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes. The [javadoc for this method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable%29) (well, actually there are 4 overloads in total) shows that it takes an `Iterable` as an argument; and `SortedSet` implements `Iterable` (via `Set`, via `Collection`).

As to whether it will be sorted, the fact is that `SortedSet` iterates over values ordered using their natural ordering, and `Iterable` is "nothing else" than an iterator.

If values weren't sorted, you could sort them anyway:

```
Joiner.on(',').join(Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(whatever));
```

Guava is a gold mine!

[edit: fix link]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will.

If `someSortedSet` iterates on the data respecting the order you want, then `join` will create the string in the right order.